# How to unsubscribe from durable topic subscription

Tags: browser, websocket, activemq-classic, stomp, jms-topic

Using Stomp WebSockets to connect to an ActiveMQ server, my extjs5 browser webapp has numerous topic subscriptions scoped to panels.

Here is an example of a topic subscription with headers:

```
var sub = this.mqClient.subscribe('/topic/Status', this.onStatusMsg, 
{"ack":"auto","persistent":true,"activemq.retroactive":true,"selector":"TaskId = 1531","activemq.subscriptionName":"status-1531"} );
```

When the user is done with a topic subscription, she closes the panel which triggers an this.mqClient.unsubscribe( sub ) call.

Reopening that panel creates a subscription with an identical activemq.subscriptionName which triggers this error response:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Durable consumer is in use for client: 2015-05-28 15:29:32-0700.0.9276173142716289 and subscriptionName: status-1531
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.TopicRegion.addConsumer(TopicRegion.java:127)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.addConsumer(RegionBroker.java:427)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedRegionBroker.addConsumer(ManagedRegionBroker.java:244)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConsumer(BrokerFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisoryBroker.addConsumer(AdvisoryBroker.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConsumer(BrokerFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConsumer(BrokerFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addConsumer(MutableBrokerFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConsumer(TransportConnection.java:667)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerInfo.visit(ConsumerInfo.java:348)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:335)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:189)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:270)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.jetty8.StompSocket.sendToActiveMQ(StompSocket.java:125)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.sendToActiveMQ(ProtocolConverter.java:199)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompSubscribe(ProtocolConverter.java:663)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompCommand(ProtocolConverter.java:257)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.jetty8.StompSocket.onMessage(StompSocket.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455$WSFrameHandler.onFrame(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:850)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketParserRFC6455.parseNext(WebSocketParserRFC6455.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.handle(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How do I close a durable topic subscription?

Answer (score 2):

Removing a durable subscription in STOMP is a two step process if the subscription is currently active (meaning the subscriber is connected and subscribed currently).

First the client must unsubscribe so that the subscription becomes inactive:

```
String frame = "UNSUBSCRIBE\n" + "destination:/topic/MyTopic" + "\n\n" + Stomp.NULL;
```

Now that the subscription is inactive it can be removed permanently by issuing an unsubscribe with the subscription name originally used to create it as follows:

```
String frame = "UNSUBSCRIBE\n" + "destination:/topic/MyTopic" + "\n" + "activemq.subscriptionName:MySubscriptionName\n\n" + Stomp.NULL;
```

This will remove the subscription and all stored messages that it held from the ActiveMQ message store.